# Excel Formula to count occurrences using date as text

Tags: excel, formula, countif

I am upgrading a "Sales pipeline" spreadsheet for my boss. At the moment he dumps all of the information onto "Sheet1", and then "Sheet2" reads it all, # of opportunities and potential value by business area and sales person. 
Now, he wants to look at month +1,+2,+3. The potential sale date in sheet1, column M are: dd.mm.yyyy formatted as text. 
The business unit is in column B. 
Currently, the # of opportunities uses:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!B$2:B$379,"MU")
```

I have been trying to modify this to countifs, however, I'm at the end of my rope :/. So far, to get the # of oppertunities in "MU" for the next month, I have:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!B$2:B$379,"MU", Value(mid(Sheet1!M$2:M$379,4,2),">="&MONTH(TODAY())+1
```

However, using a range inside mid and value inside countifs, doesn't work. 
Any help on how I can get this, ideally without a helper line would be fantastic.

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2]

Comment: It might help to show sample data, if that would be possible.

Comment: Thanks, I have attached a doctored photo of sheet1 and sheet2

Comment: Why keep date as text? If you want a non-EN-US date format ghat is easy enough.